# Difference in Load balancing on Azure LoadBancer and Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-application-gateway

I have done Load balancing on Azure using Azure Load Balancing and Application Gateway for HTTPS traffic.

In Azure Load Balancer, we can do health check at port 443 while in Application Gateway there are options to upload SSL certs and for health check we can specify a file like index.html on which we can perform health check.

I know that Application Gateway is the right way, but what is the drawback of using Azure Load balancer.

Can someone explain me this.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the following table helps understanding the difference between `Azure load balancer` and `Application Gateway`:

[image]

Comment: So whats the difference in load balancing on port 443 (TCP) using Load balancer and on HTTPS URL using Application Gateway ?

Comment: @kevinpeter If SSL offload or Layer 7 processing is not necessary, Load Balancer can be used in place of Application Gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification